# How do I get Image or Image path/location from another process?

Tags: c#, image

For example, I have a process called 'image.exe', and it has an image or picture in it.

I would like to make a program in C# that will read the memory of that process to retrieve that image, or if that seems impossible, retrieving the image location/path of that image as string would be OK as well.

I'm using ReadProcessMemory in C#, but I can't seem to find out what to do next.

So I'm assuming I would need to find the memory address of the image/string, then I will start from there.

Comment: For what program are you trying to get this to work? It will be extremely difficult to make something generic that will work for any program.

Comment: I was a project from my company, and I got assigned to it even though I'm a web developer because we're running short of programmers.

I thought it was insane too.

Comment: Am I missing something ? Don't you have any possibility to get the image from anything else than a process ?

Comment: Do you have access to the source code of the image.exe program? It would be very hard to do anything if you do not have. Or better, the creator of the program is still working with you in the same company?

Comment: @jpgrassi Actually they've lost the source code of the program, it was made in VB6 more than a decade ago.. 

They want it this way since re-creating the original program takes too much time.

Comment: @Thomas I'm afraid that's what they want, since the process that I want to get images from, gets the images from a remote server, then saves it in local hard drive with a water mark.

Comment: If you know where the process stores the images, than why you need to access the images from the process? Seriously this is caos..

Comment: @Vince, I think you should talk with them, maybe you're gonna lose too much time trying to solve this problem rather than redeveloping the application. Have you found tutorials about ReadProcessMemory ? Anyway good luck ^^

Comment: @jpgrassi Yeah, because they wanted an automated program with little to no human intervention.

Answer (score 0):

> the process that I want to get images from, gets the images from a remote server, then saves it in local hard drive with a water mark

Use [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to sniff all HTTP(S) traffic, it will list all the URLs of the files it downloads.  If they don't use HTTP(S) use WireShark Or Microsoft Message Analyzer to log the requests.

Another good tool is Process Monitor from SysInternals, it will log all network traffic and file system API calls for your process, yielding a wealth of information.

Beyond that, use a VB6 decompiler, there are several products available and you should get enough source code to figure it out.

For your initial question, you may want to try something like Resource Hacker if it's just a simple bitmap you want to extract.

Or hire a reverse engineer freelancer, this would be really easy for someone with the skills.